# PHP / Doctrine - Saving datetime with flush() outside a for() loop

Tags: php, datetime, doctrine

I have a small issue with recording three entities with a date-time property in a loop.

Here is the code I used :

```
$today = new DateTime();
$frequency = 3;

for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++) {
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString("+".($i * $frequency)." days");
    $reminder = new Reminder();
    $reminder->setNumber($i);            
    $reminder->setScheduledAt($today->add($interval));            
    $this->em->persist($reminder);            
}
$this->em->flush();
```

So, with `flush()` statement outside the loop, there are 3 reminders recorded but with the same 9 days difference in the date-time property equal to the last date-time calculated.

However, with the doctrine `flush()` inside the loop:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$frequency = 3;

for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++) {
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString("+".($i * $frequency)." days");
    $reminder = new Reminder();
    $reminder->setNumber($i);            
    $reminder->setScheduledAt($today->add($interval));            
    $this->em->persist($reminder); 
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

All three date are recorded right (meaning with a `datediff` equal to `3,6` and 9 days from the todays date) 
It seems to me that the `flush()` should stay outside the loop... what am I missing here ?

here is my entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer",length=1)
 */
private $number;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime",nullable=true)
 */
private $scheduledAt;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\WorkFlowStep" , fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $step ;
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are modifying `DateTime` object in loop.
When `flush` is outside the `loop` `scheduleAt` attribute is set to the same object with 9 days reminder. You should create three different `DateTime` objects e.g with cloning:

```
$today->add($interval);
$scheduledAt = clone $today;
$reminder->setScheduledAt($scheduleAt);

// flush outside the loop
```

In this case entities have `scheduledAt` properties set with 3 different dates.

When you have `flush` inside the loop (not recommended) you are saving to `DB` cureent `DateTime` object state with 3 days intervals.

**Note**:

The simplest solution would be to use `\DateTimeImmutable`. In such case whenever you call: `modify` method you would receive new `\DateTimeImmutable` object - cloning is not needed and you can call: `modify` in loop.

Comment: Indeed, thank you, it works perfectly ! have a nice day :)

Comment: OK, could you please accept my answer and vote on it?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: i can vote but it won't be visible for now ... again, thank you